# Why did these plants dry/burn?

Tags: plant-health, diseases, plant-care, tulips, venus-fly-trap

I bought a small venus fly trap kit to sow. Three of them sprouted and they were growing well. I had placed them at a south facing window, watering them every few days. I found them like this a few days ago. It feels like the roots are not dead, but the plants are almost burnt somehow. 
[image: venus fly trap]

The same thing has happened to my tulip bulbs that were sprouting well outside at a north facing balcony and they're in a similar situation as well. This is while my other plants at similar situation are doing pretty well. Any idea why this has happened and can I still rescue them?

[image: tulip]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VFT's can be tricky - being a bog plant, they like a lot of humidity, for one thing, so the tops may have simply desiccated. They also respond poorly when folks fertilize them, as they expect rather poor bog soils. In general, they can be somewhat difficult to grow and keep healthy.

The tulips are about 6" / 15cm higher than they want to be planted...

Answer (score 3):

I don't know anything about Venus flytraps, but in general and for any plant, The greenery wasn't accustomed to the stronger south facing sun. When you grow a plant in a protected environment, the greenery is *soft* and it gets sunburned.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I live in Ireland where there's almost no strong sun even on the south side. But thanks for the answer. (: